# VBA ADODB - Getting Parameters from parameterized query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I´m trying to get parameters names from a parameterized query stored in a MS Access database using this code:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .CommandText = "nameOfParameterizedQuery"
    .Parameters.Refresh
End With

......
```

However it doesn´t work, since Parameters collection remains empty. I´ve tried to define parameters adding the following code before the SELECT statement in the SQL query as:

```
PARAMETERS [parameter1] Datatype, [parameter2] Datatype .... ;
SELECT ....
```

But I have had no success. I´ve read that Microsoft Access ODBC and OLE DB drivers do not currently support automatic parameter population.

Is that true? Is there any way to use ADO to get parameters names from a parameterized query in a MS Access database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know but I habitually use ADO and I´d like to keep this way since, from my point of view, it makes easier a future migration to another database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this with ADODB. You just need to make a few minor edits to your VB code (see below):

```
Dim cmd as New ADODB.Command
Dim cnn as New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Provider = "blah"
cnn.Open = "blah;blah"

cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = "NameOfParameterizedQuery"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, Value:=#6/1/17#)

Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Cmd.Execute

cnn.Close
Set cmd = nothing
Set cnn = nothing
```

---

You Might Also Like: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181734/how-to-invoke-a-parameterized-ado-query-using-vba-c-java

I hope that helps.